# Created Electron app but when I run "npm start" it doesn't start the app

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I'm trying to install electron so I can create an app. I have the latest npm installed (8.3.1) and when I run "npm install electron --save-dev" I keep getting this error:

```
PS C:\Users\archa\HCIRA\blah> npm install electron --save-dev
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\archa\HCIRA\blah\node_modules\electron
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command bash -c node install.js
npm ERR! Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.
npm ERR! Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:
npm ERR! https://aka.ms/wslstore

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:        
npm ERR!     C:\Users\archa\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01- 
15T14_42_33_350Z-debug-0.log
```

"blah" is the folder where all my code is (index.js, package.json etc.). I've tried using the resources I found on Stack and GitHub but none of them have worked out for me at all. I was even told that the "--save-dev" suffix would be useful for installing Electron on Windows but it didn't work.